# ¿Que significa ##* -- dentro del mecanismo *parameter expansion* en bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estoy leyendo un programa y me encuentro con algo asi:

```
opciones="--version --status --"  
argsOpciones=${opciones##* -- }
```

Despues de imprimir ambas variables resulta que su contenido es igual pero entonces, ¿que se intenta hacer con '##* -- '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de hablar de `##*--` tenemos que hablar de su contexto, que es dentro de los brackets `{}`, en `${opciones##* -- }`

Desde ahí sabemos que podemos buscar en la sección de *parameter expansion* del manual de Bash.

Ahí se establece que en `${parametro##palabra}`, la palabra *palabra* se expandirá como si fuera un patrón.

Luego, del prefijo, **el patrón más largo que coincida será eliminado**.

Que es una paráfrasis de lo encontrado en `man 1 bash`.

Esto quiere decir que:

```
$ palabra=" --parametro ----"; echo ${palabra##* --}
#          |_____________|
#                |
#     esto sera borrado puesto que es la
#     coincidencia mas larga encontrada
#     del patrón * --, que es, todo antes de un espacio
#     seguido de dos guiones.
```

También hay otro caso semejante en el que en lugar de `${variable##patron}`, se utiliza tan sólo uno, `${variable#patron}`

En este caso, donde sólo se utiliza una almohadilla, busca la coincidencia **más corta** del patrón. Es decir:

```
$ palabra=" --parametro ----"; echo ${palabra#* --}
#          |__|
#           |
#    Esto sera borrado porque es la coincidencia
#    mas corta.
```

**Nota importante**: con las almohadillas (`#` o `##`), se remueve el prefijo. En cambio, con el símbolo del porcentaje (`%`, o `%%`), se remueve el sufijo. Por eso es que en ambos casos se empieza **de izquierda a derecha**, porque es el prefijo.

En otras palabras, esas expansiones borran:

1. Prefijo (de izquierda a derecha), cuando son `#` y `##`. Donde con `#` es la "menor" coincidencia, y con `##` la mayor.
2. Sufijo (de derecha a izquierda), cuando son `%` y `%%`. Donde con `%` es la "menor" coincidencia y con `%%` la mayor.

Comment: Gracias compa, ¿es posible que te pueda contactar por telegram?

Comment: De igual manera cuando uso solamente `argsOpciones=${opciones#* --}` el resultado es el mismo es decir no es borrado la coincidencia mas corta. Vi que para que se borre es necesario tener un espacio entre el '--' con 'opcion' es decir debe ser `opciones="-- op1 -- op2 -- op3"`, entonces de esa manera si se estaria borrando.

Comment: Cuando pones: `opciones="-- op1 -- op2 -- op3";echo "${opciones#* --}"` va a resultar en " --op2 -- op3". Porque le indicas que el prefijo es todo lo que esté antes de un espacio, seguido de dos guiones, y eso es `-- op1 --`. Que sería el prefijo que se borraría.

Comment: Algo así: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8bO.png

Comment: Pregunto para ver si entendi:  
¿Se puede decir que con `#` encuentra la primera coincidencia del patron y borra todo el texto que existe a la izquierda junto con el patron?,¿Lo mismo haria `##` pero con la ultima coincidencia?.¿`%` busca el primer patron de derecha a izquierda y borra todo lo que existe a la derecha junto con el patron?,¿`%%` lo mismo pero con la ultima coincidencia del patron?  
Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: No es ni la primera ni la última coincidencia. Sino la más corta o la más larga. Aunque no sé en qué medida sean lo mismo.